# Is the videojs 'control bar' supposed to size to the width of the video or of the container?

Tags: javascript, electron, video.js, lightgallery

I have an `Electron` desktop app which has a feature of showing a user's local videos in a 'lightbox' using [jQuery lightgallery](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/). It's a bit of a complicated setup as I am using an `iframe` loaded with `videojs` within `lightgallery` to present the videos.

I've wrestled with being able to handle videos of varying aspect ratios – settings that work for 16:9 don't work for 4:3, etc.

The best I've got so far is the first image below: the video's aspect ratio is preserved but the "control bar" fills the entire container which `lightgallery` has provided.

Is there some way to get the "control bar" to size to the width of the video?

---

**Further details**
All the videos are loaded dynamically so I don't know their aspect ratios. The first two images below result from using:

```
<video id="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-16-9"></video>
```

I've tried using `vjs-fluid` or `vjs-fill` but that resulted in the third image below with the scroll bars.

Video: 4:3

[image]

Video: 16:9

[image]

Video: 4:3 - Using `vjs-fluid`

[image]

---

**Player set-up code**

```
   var player = videojs("videoPlayer", {
      controls: true,
      autoplay: false,
      preload: 'auto'
    }, function () {
      this.src(videoPath);
      this.poster(posterPath);
      this.load();
    });
```

Comment: Hmm...I'd say that the control-bar in the top example IS sized to the video.  Because, I think the real video width is larger than you're thinking.  i.e the video width includes vertical black-bars on each side of the viewable area of interest.

Comment: @Dave – thanks but that is not the case. The top video is 4:3 aspect ration and there are no black bars in the source.